# Problema con urls en Django

Tags: python, django

Me encuentro realizando una pagina en modo de practica, con Django. Hice un middleware que corrobora si los datos del usuario estan completos, si esto no es asi, te redirecciona hacia la view para completar el perfil. El programa responde todo bien hasta el punto de redireccionar, me sale un error 404. Yo creo que es porque no indico a que usuario quiero editar.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada usuario pueda editar su perfil sin tener que poner en el url por ejemplo: /users/profile/complete, y no tener que poner /users/profile/complete/(usuario).

Dejo el codigo.

views.py

```
class UpdateProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
"""Update profile view."""

template_name = 'users/update_profile.html'
model = Profile
fields = ['phone_number', 'picture', 'address']

def get_object(self):
    """Return user's profile."""
    return self.request.user.profile

def get_success_url(self):
    """Return to user's profile."""
    username = self.object.user.username
    return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': username})
```

urls.py

```
path(
    route='profile/complete/',
    view=views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(),
    name='complete_perfil'
)
```

middleware.py

```
class ProfileCompletionMiddleware:

def __init__(self, get_response):
    """Middleware initialization."""
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            profile = request.user.profile
            if not profile.picture:
                if request.path not in [reverse('users:complete_perfil'), reverse('users:logout')]:
                    return redirect('users:complete_perfil')

    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

picture = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='users/pictures',
    blank=True,
    null=True
)

address = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    """Return username."""
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: Adjunta el código de tu middleware y del modelo `Profile`. Por otra parte quieres redireccionar a la vista `UpdateProfileView`, verdad? **y a que URLs especificas no quieres que acceda el usuario si no a completado su perfil?**

Comment: La idea es que si por ejemplo, te falta la foto de perfil, te redireccione a la pagina para editar el perfil. Pero que en la url no tenga que poner el id del usuario, solo se muestre /profile/complete. Se entiende? Adjunto el codigo de lo que me pides en el post!

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu middleware debería ser así:

```
import re

class ProfileCompletionMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Utilisamos expresiones regulares para detectar solicitudes a archivos multimedia y estaticos
        if not re.search('^/media/', request.path) and not re.search('^/static/', request.path):
            if not request.user.is_anonymous and not request.user.is_staff:
                if not request.user.profile.picture:
                    if request.path not in [....]:
                        return redirect(...)

        return self.get_response(request)
```

Toma en cuenta que **el método [`__call__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#init-get-response) se ejecuta cada ves que se hace una solicitud** y el problema de tu middleware es que si el usuario no a completado el perfil, le bloquea a dicho usuario, los archivos multimedia y estaticos.

*(Lo probé y me bloqueaba los archivos multimedia, los estilos no, pero preferible evitar posibles inconvenientes)*

---

> *Lo que quiero hacer es que cada usuario pueda editar su perfil sin tener que poner en el url por ejemplo: /users/profile/complete, y no
> tener que poner /users/profile/complete/(usuario)*

Tu middleware, hace eso, no se porque dices esto, si justamente el middleware redirecciona a dichas URLs sin que el usuario deba escribir la URL, es mas ni debería suceder eso, así que es raro que se te pase eso por la cabeza xD.

Por otra parte si quieres generar una URL asi `/users/profile/complete/(usuario)`, lo puedes hacer así:

```
reverse('users:complete_perfil') + f'/{self.request.user.username}/'
reverse('users:complete_perfil') + f'/{request.user.username}/'
reverse('users:complete_perfil') + f'/{user.username}/'
```

---

Por otra parte la vista `UpdateProfileView`, no necesita un `id` o algo asi, primero porque la URL que apunta a dicha vista no recibe ningún parámetro y segundo porque obtienes al perfil asi: `self.request.user.profile`, en el método `get_object`, así que no entiendo porque quieres pasarle un `id` o un `username`, a la vista, pues no es necesario.

Eso debería solucionar el "problema", aunque lo único que hice fue mejorar tu middleware, porque tu middleware ya cumplía con el objetivo. Espero haberte ayudado.